# Transform text that matches a pattern to uppercase

Tags: search-replace

Searching `/<pattern>` in a document highlights text in some places like this:

```
some text ...
match1 some text ...
some text match2
...
match3 text match4
...
```

Is there a way to make all the matches uppercase with `:%s//<something>/g`? I currenty do this kind of things by using the `gn` operator, but I would like to know a better way.

Comment: `:%s/match. some text/\U&/g`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check `:h :s%` for substitute options, including:

```
      \U      following characters made uppercase, until \E      *s/\U*
```

So

```
:%s/word/\U&/g
```

will replace all `word` to `WORD`.

Comment: If you are using % do you need to use g as well?

Comment: @elmclose depends on what you need. `/g` will replace all matches in a given `:s` range. All matches in a single line, all matches in all range lines...

Comment: @elmclose not really. Consider `word word` and try to change `:%s/word/hello`